# Dynamic floating 2 column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

http://jsfiddle.net/ny3es0dk/

```
#floating_body_container {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 5px;
float: left;
width: 450px;
height: auto;
margin: 5px;
background: #eee;
}
```

I am trying to create a responsive "update stream" using only html/css (although if absolutely neccesary I could use js/jquery). The problem is that every new div on a new "line" will only start at the bottom of the taller div from the last line. Ideally the div would go to the side with the shorter div above it. You can see the problem illustrated on the jsfiddle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#floating_body_container:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

Solves the problem.

Comment: it does only in this specific case with those sizes. It won't on random sized divs

Comment: I've deployed it on the live site and added 5 more divs and it works perfectly. All different sizes.